# Bash Script Compare and Run a Command

Tags: bash, shell, unix, if-statement, compare

I have a shell script that gives me a txt file containing certain numbers. 
For instance, " 48 347 345 221 1029 3943 1245 7899 " .
It only contains one line.

I want to trigger another shell script if one of those numbers exceeds 500.
How can and compare the numbers and run the shell script?
Thanks in advance

```
cat text.txt | if [ awk '{print $1}' -ge 500 ] then command.sh fi
```

Comment: What have you tried so far ? Sounds like you could easily achieve that with a regex. Check the [`=~`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/340440/bash-test-what-does-do) operator in bash.

Comment: I opened the file with cat, then tried to compare with 500 with if -ge operator combined with awk. Which is complicated and failed, I believe there should be single line operator cat text.txt | if [ awk '{print $1}' -ge 500 ] then command.sh fi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `awk` you can try this:

```
awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)if($i > 500)exit 1}' text.txt || ./command.sh
```

`command.sh` will be executed if the `awk` command exits with a non-zero code because of the `||` operator.

Comment: What if you fumble-finger the execution? I don't think I like running the command on error exit. How about `$: awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)if($i > 500) { print "runit"; exit; } }' text.txt | grep -q runit &&  ./command.sh`

Comment: @PaulHodges I understand your point, how about `awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)if($i > 500) exit 0} END {exit 1}' text.txt && ./command.sh`

Comment: That would also work, but what if it failed because of permissions. or something unexpected? I usually make ANY unhandled exception in a script fatal, and this would crash the run every time it didn't see a value. If you just really want to do it in `awk`, maybe `awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)if($i > 500) { system("./command.sh"); exit; } }' text.txt` But it's only one line, right? I think `awk` may be overkill here. YMMV. OP will need to decide what works for him, and maybe I'm overthinking it, but I prefer readability that fits with the overall style of the author.  To each his own. :)

Comment: I actually agree with you that my answer is not the best option here specially when used in production scripts. But for quick and dirty use cases, this might just be enough.

Answer (score 0):

Throw the file contents into an array -

```
$: declare -a lst=( $(<text.txt) )
```

Then run a quick loop. If you want to run the command for each hit,

```
$: for n in "${lst[@]}"
do (( n > 500 )) && echo "command.sh # $n > 500"
done
command.sh # 1029 > 500
command.sh # 3943 > 500
command.sh # 1245 > 500
command.sh # 7899 > 500
```

If you just want a quick and dirty version,

```
$: for n in $(<text.txt); do (( n > 500 )) && command.sh; done
```

But I recommend you take the time to do the horribly complicated *2* steps, lol

If you want to run it just once if *any* number is over 500,

```
$: for n in "${lst[@]}"
do (( n > 500 )) && { echo "command.sh # $n > 500"; break; }
done
command.sh # 1029 > 500
```

And don't use cat like that. Try to never use cat like that.

If you *REALLY needed the file as input to an `if`, then do this:

```
if condition
then action
fi < text.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a simple for loop like this:

```
for n in $(cat test.txt)
do
    if [ $n -gt 500 ]; then
        something.sh
    fi
done
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply :

```
[[ "48 347 345 221 500" =~ ([ ][5-9][0-9][0-9]|[ ][1-9][0-9]{3,}) ]] && echo "Hi"
Hi
[[ "48 347 345 221" =~ ([ ][5-9][0-9][0-9]|[ ][1-9][0-9]{3,}) ]] && echo "Hi"
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Only print Hi when a number exceeds 500, so with 501, 1500 and 5000.

Comment: Print Hi when the first number is 600 (without a leading space).

Answer (score 0):

When you don't want to convert the sring to numbers, it will become nasty.
Look for a number with at least 4 digits (first not 0), or a number with 3 digits, first 5 or higher will give

```
# incorrect, includes 500 
grep -Eq "([1-9][0-9]|[5-9])[0-9][0-9]" text.txt && command.sh
```

This will also perform `command.sh` with number 500.

```
# incorrect, will fail for 5000 and 1500
grep -E "([1-9][0-9]|[5-9])[0-9][0-9]" text.txt | grep -qv 500 && command.sh
```

Fixing it becomes too complex. `awk` seems  to be the most natural way.
An artificial way is converted the input to lines with one number and add an extra line with the border:

```
(echo "500 border"; tr ' '  '\n' < text.txt) |
   sort -n |
   tail -1 | 
   grep -qv "border" && command.sh
```